# Effiecient way to do static ComboBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a static `ComboBox` in my wpf applicaiton, that loads space followed by 0-9. I have the following code it does the job what I need, but I dont feel its a great way to do. Any suggestion or opinion will be appreciated.

**`Test.xaml`**

```
<ComboBox Name="cbImportance" 
          Text="{Binding SelectedStory.ImportanceList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}" 
          Loaded="cbImportance_Loaded"
          Grid.Column="1"
          d:LayoutOverrides="Height" 
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          Margin="0,9" 
          SelectionChanged="cbImportance_SelectionChanged" />
```

**`Test.xaml.cs`**

```
private void cbImportance_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> data = new List<string>();
    data.Add("");
    data.Add("0");
    data.Add("1");
    data.Add("2");
    data.Add("3");
    data.Add("4");
    data.Add("5");
    data.Add("6");
    data.Add("7");
    data.Add("8");
    data.Add("9");

    // ... Get the ComboBox reference.
    var cbImportance = sender as ComboBox;

    // ... Assign the ItemsSource to the List.
    cbImportance.ItemsSource = data;

    // ... Make the first item selected.
    cbImportance.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Which one is the efficient way to load the static value in to `ComboBox`:

1. Through XAML (suggested by Anatoliy Nikolaev)
2. xaml.cs (Like Above)
3. Create constructor in `ViewModel` and load the static value back to `ComboBox`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In WPF has support for arrays of objects in XAML through a markup extension. This corresponds to the `x:ArrayExtension` XAML type [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752340%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You can do this:

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<x:Array x:Key="ParametersArray" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
    <sys:String>0</sys:String>
    <sys:String>1</sys:String>
    <sys:String>2</sys:String>
    <sys:String>3</sys:String>
    ...
</x:Array>

<ComboBox Name="ParameterComboBox"
          SelectedIndex="0"
          ItemsSource="{StaticResource ParametersArray}" ... />
```

For setting empty string in `x:Array` use a *`static`* member:

```
<x:Array x:Key="ParametersArray" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
    <x:Static Member="sys:String.Empty" />
    <sys:String>0</sys:String>
    <sys:String>1</sys:String>
    <sys:String>2</sys:String>
    <sys:String>3</sys:String>
    ...
</x:Array>
```

If you need to define a static `ComboBox` with numbers `Int32` type, it can be even shorter:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Int32Collection x:Key="Parameters">0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9</Int32Collection>
</Window.Resources>

<ComboBox Width="100" 
          Height="30" 
          ItemsSource="{StaticResource Parameters}" />
```

Or like this:

```
<ComboBox Width="100" Height="30">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <Int32Collection>0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9</Int32Collection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,is that good idea create a constructor in view model and load the value in to view ?

Comment: @Usher: I think is a bad idea. `ViewModel` ideally should not know about the `View`. But in your case, if in ViewModel will not mean `ComboBox` controls and the like, but will only `List<>` or collection that will be fine.

Comment: @Usher: Where to set the value - it's your decision. There are several parameters, such as: where are you comfortable with it, how often to change the value in the list, etc. In this situation, it is more convenient to me to work in XAML, since there is less code in the `ViewModel`, and the final code looks more readable.

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to use enumerable object as ItemsSource, based on `{StaticResource}` or `{Binding}` or other dependancy property. Binding is preferred way, because it meets MVVM approach, wich is recommended for WPF apps.

### MVVM way

With binding we have list of values as property of ViewModel object, which is set as `DataContext` in terms of WPF. So, here is **binding example**:

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<SomeObject> Items
    {
        get { /* ... */ }
    }
    public SomeObject SelectedItem
    {
        get { /* ... */ }
        set { /* ... */ }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Window
    x:Class="Project1.MainWindow">
    <ComboBox
        ItemsSource={Binding Items}
        SelectedItem={Binding SelectedItem} />
</Window>
```

### String array as static resource

This solution was finely illustrated in previous answer by @AnatoliyNikolaev.

### XmlDataProvider

Sometimes you have to operate on complex values which have visible title. Putting it in ViewModel is senseless - better use XAML features. That's what it looks like:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="YesNo" XPath="Items">
            <x:XData>
                <Items xmlns="">
                    <Item Header="Yes" Value="1"/>
                    <Item Header="No" Value="0"/>
                </Items>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource YesNo},XPath=*,Mode=OneTime}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Value,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            SelectedValuePath="@Value"
            DisplayMemberPath="@Header">
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I just edited my complicated name :). And +1 for illustration MVVM way.